# Navigate from last item to first item in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, androidx

I'm using a `RecyclerView` with list items that contain an `EditText` control with the `android:imeOptions` set to `actionNext`. When I tap the `actionNext` button on the on-screen keyboard the focus goes to the `EditText` control of the next list item as expected. If the focus is on the `EditText` of the last list item that is visible on the screen then the `RecyclerView` creates the next list item and its `EditText` control receives the focus as I would expect.

The problem I have is with what happens when I tap the `actionNext` button when the `EditText` control of the last list item of the entire collection of data items has the focus. I would like the `RecyclerView` to scroll to the top and set the focus on the `EditText` control of the list item which shows the first item of the data item collection, but the focus actually goes to the `EditText` control of the first list item that is visible.

For example if I have 8 items in my collection and only the last 5 items fit on the screen, when I tap the `actionNext` button on the `EditText` control of the last item, the focus goes to the `EditText` control of the 4th item instead of the 1st item as I'd like.

I tried to achieve this behavior using an `OnKeyListener` on the `EditText` control but it won't fire when I tap the `actionNext` button. Could someone point me in the right direction?